# How to save check box position in recyclerview?

Tags: android, checkbox, position, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a list of checkListItems. List item has a check box. I want to save the status of the item. Status is saved as 0 or 1.

I am showing the check box checked or unchecked based on status 0 or 1.

It shows correct sometimes but when I scroll up and down more items gets checked or unchecked which I have not done manually.

Adapter:

```
    public class CheckListItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckListItemAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<CheckListItem> checkListItems;
    Context context;
    private String status;

    private final OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(CheckListItem item);
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, budget;
        public RelativeLayout parent;
        private CheckBox checkBox;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            budget =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.budget);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        }


        public void bind(final CheckListItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    public CheckListItemAdapter(List<CheckListItem> checkListItems,Context context,OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.checkListItems = checkListItems;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.checklist_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final CheckListItem item = checkListItems.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.budget.setText(item.getBudget());

        status = item.getStatus();

        if(status.equals("1"))
        {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
        if(status.equals("0")) {

            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {

                    status = "1";

                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    params.put("checklistItemId", item.getCheckListItemId());
                    params.put("budget",item.getBudget());
                    params.put("text", item.getTitle());
                    params.put("time_due", item.getDateTime());
                    params.put("reminder",item.getReminder());
                    params.put("status", status);


                    new UpdateCheckListItemsAsyncTask(context).execute(params);


                } else

                {
                    status = "0";

                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    params.put("checklistItemId", item.getCheckListItemId());
                    params.put("budget",item.getBudget());
                    params.put("text", item.getTitle());
                    params.put("time_due", item.getDateTime());
                    params.put("reminder",item.getReminder());
                    params.put("status", status);

                    new UpdateCheckListItemsAsyncTask(context).execute(params);

                }

            }

        });


        holder.bind(checkListItems.get(position), listener);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return checkListItems.size();
    }

}
```

What's going wrong here? How can I save the position of checkbox?

Thank you..

Comment: How do you get the information about the position of the item that has been checked ?

Suppose user checked 5th item in the list, how do you know its 5th position ?
And when you update your item after checking, you are not retrieving that object for updation, instead you are creating new Hashmap, everytime item is checked.

Comment: I want to save it in the server I have an asyncTask to update the item so I am calling that. @intellignt_idiot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Had faced a similar Issue.

The thing is, in the RecyclerView, the ViewHolder is Recycled. So, until you `remove the OnCheckedChangeListener`, the Items will refer to the old OnCheckedChangeListener.

```
    if(status.equals("1"))
    {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
    if(status.equals("0")) {

        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
```

These lines actually triggers the old onCheckedChangedListener.

You can try this.

1. add the line `holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);` as the first Line of  `onBindViewHolder`
2. You can implement an interface call and shift the `onCheckedChanged` logic to that interface call using `getLayoutPosition()`

As to your second question,

you can use `HashSet` to store the data of checked list item.
Your way of storing it in class object is also  fine

EDIT- Added Code for reference

```
    public class CheckListItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckListItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ...
            ..

    public CheckListItemAdapter(List<CheckListItem> checkListItems, Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.checkListItems = checkListItems;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

      ....
        ....

            if(item.getStatus().equals("1"))
        {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {

            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }



    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        budget = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.budget);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
             checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int pos = getLayoutPosition();
                    CheckListItem currentItem=checkListItems.get(pos);
//to remove redundant calls to network while scrolling
                    if ( isChecked){
                        if (currentItem.getStatus().equals("1")) {
                            return;
                        } else {
                            currentItem.setStatus("1");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (currentItem.getStatus().equals("0")) {
                            return;
                        } else {
                            currentItem.setStatus("0");
                        }
                    }
//network call, when check is changed
                    checkChangedLogic(checkListItems.get(pos), isChecked);
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Note-

I have implemented a simple logic in  `onCheckedChanged` to remove redundant calls. Since you mentioned they are network calls, this is necessary.

Comment: where to use get layout position? Could you please explain with code? @Harshit

Comment: so I don't have to set the if condition? How to show the checkBoxes as checked ? without checked changed? @Harshit

Comment: Which if condition?

Comment: You can use hashSet. Wait a while then I will add the whole proper complete thing.

Comment: if(status == "1"){checkbox.setChecked(true)}, and if I move onCheckChangedListener inMyViewHolder, the item object is inaccessible. @Harshit

Comment: @user6265109 Re-edited. I think this should fix your doubts

Comment: tried your solution, it's not showing any check box as checked though the status is "1", @Harshit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116307/discussion-between-harshit-and-user6265109).